# 'GetPreValueAsString' not working in Umbraco 7

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I am getting the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'GetPreValueAsString' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Umbraco' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My code snippet where this error occurs is:

```
foreach (var member2 in ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService.GetAllMembers().OrderBy(member2 => member2.Name)){
    var codeTheme = Umbraco.GetPreValueAsString(member2.GetValue<int>("codeTheme"));
    <p>@codeTheme</p>
}
```

I am using the latest version of Umbraco, I think it is because I need @using Umbracomagicmissingreference at the top of the page, but I have no idea which one is missing.

I have a dropdown list in the member area which I am trying to get the text values from so I can create a form that has these values.

Thank-you

Comment: Can you post the full view please? Is the view using a custom model, or an Umbraco one?

Comment: I found changing the line to `umbraco.library.GetPreValueAsString(member2.GetValue<int>("codeTheme")` looped through the members and output their chosen option. My issue is I want to loop through all the available options in the drop down list.

Comment: So you want to get all of the possible pre-values for a given list?

Comment: Yes I do, I thought fixing the above issue would get me closer but is hasn't really...

Comment: Found it:

   `XPathNodeIterator iterator = umbraco.library.GetPreValues(1124);
   iterator.MoveNext();
   XPathNodeIterator preValues = iterator.Current.SelectChildren("preValue", "");

   <ul>
    @while (preValues.MoveNext())
    {
     string preValue = preValues.Current.Value;

     <li>@preValue</li>
    }
   </ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to fix this, I changed the following line:

```
var branch = Umbraco.GetPreValueAsString(member2.GetValue<int>("codeTheme"));
```

to

```
var codeTheme = umbraco.library.GetPreValueAsString(member2.GetValue<int>("c‌​odeTheme")
```